# Java power mock unit test a method having Thread.Sleep

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am trying to unit test a method which has a call to Thread.sleep.

```
public Boolean waitForUpscale(){
   String res = someObject.upTheResources();
   Thread.sleep(20000);
   Boolean status = someObject.checkForStatus();
   return status;
}
```

While testing this the test also sleeps due `Thread.sleep` I have to avoid the test to sleep when testing.

UPDATE:

I added this test:

```
@Test
    public void downscaleTest() throws Exception {
        when(someservice.downScaleResources()).thenReturn("DONE");
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
        doNothing().when(Thread.class, "sleep", anyLong());
        Boolean res = Whitebox.invokeMethod(myController, "downscaleALL");

        assertTrue(res);
    }
```

When I debug this it works. But when I run the test normally it fails giving below exception:

```
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

-> at com.mypackage.controller.MyController.downscaleALL(MyControllerTest.java:265)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

Adding downScaleAll method

```
private Boolean downscaleALL() {
    try {
        String downScaleResources = someservice.downScaleResources();
        if (downScaleResources.equals("DONE")) {
            Thread.sleep(20000); // 20s
            log.info("DOWNSCALING THE RESOURCES NOW");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while downscaling the resources");
        log.error(e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add prepareForTest annotation? Without the complete test class, its hard to help

Comment: Yes I have @PrepareForTest({MyController.class, Thread.class})

Comment: can u add `downscaleALL` method of your controller class, which you are calling

Comment: adding the `downscaleALL` method

Comment: Can u also put your complete test class. How r u injecting someservice mock into your controller? Also why r u using whitebox to call, you can directly call mycontroller.downscaleAll() isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what @Elevate mentioned, you should not mock the types which you do not own. But if you still have to do it, you can do it like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({<ClassWherewaitForUpscaleFunctionisLocated>.class, Thread.class})
public class Mytest {
    @Test
    public void testStaticVoid() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
        doNothing().when(Thread.class, "sleep", anyLong());
        .........
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should only [mock types you own](http://www.jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf) so, if you want to mock the call to `Thread.sleep()`, you should extract that into a type you own (e.g. `ThreadSleeper`) and can therefore mock. Better still, rewrite to avoid the sleep if you can. Sleeps are usually a code smell (cutting corners).